# Example for PHP _call() function

Tags: php

Guys I just came across the __call() PHP function. I tried to understand what this is used through the manual here http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call
But all that is mentioned here is that

> __call() is triggered when invoking inaccessible methods in an object context.

which is not really clear honestly. I tried looking for other examples online, but they all seem complicated. Can anyone explain using a simple example what is __call() and what is it good for?

Comment: `__call` is executed when you try to invoke non-existent method in class. PHP page you provided has an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider this:

```
class Foo
{
    public function __call($name, $args)
    {
        echo "you tried to call method $name with these args:";
        print_r($args);
    }
}

$foo = new Foo();
$foo->bar($args);
```

Note there is no method named `bar`. Normally, calling it will produce an error. However, in this case, you've defined a `__call()` method. So, instead of generating an error, PHP will invoke this method, passing it the name of the method you tried to call, and the arguments you tried to call it with.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This helps!: )