# create dynamic method of the class in php

Tags: php, oop

I would like to create a dynamic method in the class.

I've tried doing this:

```
class abc
{
   public $function_prefix;

   function __construct() {
          $prefix = new ups_generic_name();
          $function_prefix = $prefix->class_prefix.'_shipping_array';
   }        

   function $this->function_prefix( $packages ) 
   {
   }
}
```

But it triggers an error.

Comment: I don't know your actual use case, but be aware that this approach (create a dynamic method in the class) is very bad.. it has nothing to do with oop

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve using a method like this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Example for PHP \_call() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51310153/example-for-php-call-function)

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do is a good idea. And the approach you have tried is certainly not valid PHP. But if you read the target dupe, and about the `_call` [magic method](http://php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call) in general, you'll be able to do what you want.

Comment: helps if you tell us your error

Comment: You could do it with anonymous functions, but a better question would be why?  What benefit would this offer over just using subclasses to specialize a class to specific use cases?

Comment: what error does it trigger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NOTE: What you're proposing is a bad idea!**  I've never encountered a problem in nearly 15 years of PHP development that could only be solved by dynamically adding methods to a class, or even where doing so would be the best solution, and this kind of magic will only lead to confusion later on when some poor sod has to come back and modify or bugfix what you've done.  The fact that you think you need to do this is a big red flag that there's something fundamentally wrong with your design and you should reconsider it.

Also note I've not actually tested this.

If you add an [anonymous method](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) to a class and implement the [__call magic method](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call) then you can produce something along the lines of what you're trying to implement.

```
class ScaryClass
{
    public function __call($method, array $args)
    {
        call_user_func_array($this->$method, $args);
    }
}

$scaryInstance = new ScaryClass;
$scaryInstance->scaryMethod = function($argument) 
{
    echo $argument;
}

$scaryInstance->scaryMethod("This code is really scary and I feel like a terrible person for having even written it");
```

However, this has all kinds of problems, the biggest being that the anonymous function has no idea of the context it's being called in and therefore you can't use $this or make any assumptions about the hosting class at all.  This makes this trick almost useless in practice.

So TL:DR, yes you can do that (sort of), but it won't work very well, it will be very confusing and there are no benefits to doing it and a huge number of drawbacks.  Now you know how to do it, **don't do it**.

Comment: A much better idea would be to declare an abstract function (and therefore make your class abstract) and then make subclasses that implement the abstract class.  that way you can modify the base class behaviour based on far more solid OOP principles.  Just instantiate the right class for the behaviour you want.